# Splitting up one row/column into one or mulitple rows over two columns

Tags: sql-server, etl

First post here! I'm trying to update a stored procedure in my employer's Data Warehouse that's linking two tables on their ID's. The stored procedure is based on 2 columns in Table A. It's primary key, and a column that contains the primary keys from Table B and it's domain in one column. Note that it physically only needs Table A since the ID's from B are in there. The old code used some PATINDEX/SUBSTRING code that assumes two things:

- The FK's are *always* 7 characters long
- Domain strings look like this "@xx-yyyy" where xx has to be two characters and yyyy four.

The problem however:

- We've recently outgrown the 7-digit FK's and are now looking at 7 or 8 digits
- Longer domain strings are implemented (where xx may be between 2 or 15 characters)
- Sometimes there is no domain string. Just some FK's, delimited the same way.
- The code is poorly documented and includes some ID exceptions (not a problem, just annoying)

Some info:

- The Data Warehouse follows the Data Vault method and this procedure is stored on SQL Server and is triggered by SSIS. Subsequent to this procedure the HUB and Satellites are updated so in short: I can't just create a new stored procedure but instead will try to integrate my code into the old stored procedure.
- The servers is running on SQL Server 2012 so I can't use `string_split`
- This platform is dying out so I just have to "keep it running" for this year.
- An ID and domain are *always* seperated with one space
- If a record has no foreign keys it will *always* have an empty string
- When a record has multiple (foreign) ID's it will always use the same delimiting, even when the individual FK's have no domain string next to it. Delimiter looks like this:

  ```
  "12345678 @xx-xxxx[CR][CR][CR][LF]12345679 @yy-xxxx"
  ```

I've managed to create some code that will assign row numbers and is flexible in recognising the amount of FK's.

This is a piece of the old code:

```
DECLARE 
    @MAXCNT INT = (SELECT MAX(ROW) FROM #Worktable),
    @C_ID INT,
    @R_ID INT,
    @SOURCE CHAR(5),
    @STRING VARCHAR(20),
    @VALUE CHAR(20),
    @LEN INT,
    @STARTSTRINGLEN INT =0,
    @MAXSTRINGLEN INT,

    @CNT INT = 1

WHILE @CNT <= @MAXCNT
BEGIN

SELECT @LEN=LEN(REQUESTS),@STRING =REQUESTS, @C_ID =C_ID  FROM #Worktable WHERE ROW = @CNT

--1 REQUEST RELATED TO ONE CHANGE
IF @LEN < 17
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #ChangeRequest
    SELECT @C_ID,SUBSTRING(@STRING,0,CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%-xxxx%',@STRING) = 0  THEN @LEN+1 ELSE PATINDEX('%-xxxx%',@STRING)-4 END)
    --SELECT @STRING AS STRING, @LEN AS LENGTH
    END
ELSE 
-- MULTIPLE REQUESTS RELATED TO ONE CHANGE
    SET @STARTSTRINGLEN = 0
    WHILE @STARTSTRINGLEN<@LEN
    BEGIN
    SET @MAXSTRINGLEN = (SELECT PATINDEX('%-xxxx%',SUBSTRING(@STRING,@STARTSTRINGLEN,@STARTSTRINGLEN+17)))+7

    INSERT INTO #ChangeRequest
    --remove CRLF
    SELECT @C_ID,
    REPLACE(REPLACE( 
        substring(@string,@STARTSTRINGLEN+1,@MAXSTRINGLEN )
    , CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
    SET @STARTSTRINGLEN=@STARTSTRINGLEN+@MAXSTRINGLEN

    IF @MAXSTRINGLEN = 0 BEGIN SET @STARTSTRINGLEN = @len END

    END
    SET @CNT = @CNT + 1;
END;
```

Since this loop is assuming fixed lengths I need to make it more flexible. My code:

```
(CASE WHEN LEN([Requests]) = 0
            THEN 0
            ELSE (LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(Requests,CHAR(10),'|'),CHAR(13),''))-LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(Requests,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')))+1
         END)
```

This consistently shows the accurate number of FK's and thus the number of rows to be created. Now I need to create a loop in which to physically create these rows and split the FK and domain into two columns.

**Source** table:

```
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Some ID |                                 Other ID's                                 |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1 | 21                                                                         |
|       2 | 31 @xxx-xxx                                                                |
|       3 | 41 @xxx-xxx[CR][CR][CR][LF]42 @yyy-xxx[CR][CR][CR][LF]43 @zzz-xxx          |
|       4 | 51[CR][CR][CR][LF]52[CR][CR][CR][LF]53 @xxx-xxx[CR][CR][CR][LF]54 @yyy-xxx |
|       5 | <empty string>                                                             |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Target** table:

```
+-----+----------------+----------------+
| SID |      OID       |     Domain     |
+-----+----------------+----------------+
|   1 | 21             | <empty string> |
|   2 | 31             | xxx-xxx        |
|   3 | 41             | xxx-xxx        |
|   3 | 42             | yyy-xxx        |
|   3 | 43             | zzz-xxx        |
|   4 | 51             | <empty string> |
|   4 | 52             | <empty string> |
|   4 | 53             | xxx-xxx        |
|   4 | 54             | yyy-xxx        |
|   5 | <empty string> | <empty string> |
+-----+----------------+----------------+
```

Currently all rows are created but every one beyond the first for each SID is empty.

Comment: Find `DelimitedSplit8K` or `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD` sp.